# Check LDAP attribute access rights from .net code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ldap

In my vb.net code, I'm using LDAP server for authentication, and I want to update attribute values for user only if the user has write permission on that attribute. 
I would like to know how to do this. I did search some existing articles and questions, but could not find any solution.
Any help you provide is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just update without checking for permission. If you have permission, the update will succeed, if you don't, ignore or handle the exception/error you'll get, but you won't have changed the attribute.

Comment: I wanted to show a list of attributes with an attribute as read only if the user does not have permission. I'll do what you suggested if I can't find a better way. Thanks